# Alternative to an electric iron?

Tags: home, clothing

I often go to a location where there is no electricity. When I need to press my clothes, I have no idea of an alternative method. I also often face this problem in my city because of loadshedding. Please tell me if anyone knows some hacks to remove wrinkles from clothes.

Comment: does this location have access to a shower with hot water?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I watched videos oh life hacks and one of them is you put clothes under the mattress and under the cushions of sofas. the weight of them will help to flatten the clothes and remove some wrinkles.
A way for me to save is to use the free iron from the office and iron my shirts there. Saves me money in electricity.

another way is to spray a bit of water and then using a hair dryer on top of the water marks. This helps to remove wrinkles easily.

Comment: Using a hair dryer won't work as there is no electricity.

Comment: Damp it in water and hang it so that the wind and sunlight will hit the clothes...

Answer (score 5):

If you happen to have a way to heat a pot or pan, such as a wood stove or campfire, you could use this in leiu of a normal iron.  As well, you could try using a small, portable vintage iron such as [this one](https://free3d.com/3d-model/old-clothes-iron-small-v1--920656.html); they can be very cheap to obtain, and with care, will last a lifetime [many I have seen lasted several lifetimes].  Another option would be to dampen the area lightly, and add a flat, heavy weight to the wrinkled area for a while -- this can remove some wrinkles in my experience.  Lastly, you could try dampening and hanging the clothes, although this will work well only for certain materials.

Comment: Ok i understand but little confusion about heavy weight ,will you please explain it?

Comment: @user10443184 -- The weight could be something like a thick book's worth of weight -- not very heavy, but enough to flatten the wrinkles when combined with the light dampness.  Perhaps a few pounds would be about all I would normally use.  On a business trip, my laptop has always worked in a pinch (of course with something waterproof between it and the laptop) to remove some wrinkling when the hotel does not have an iron.  As that example illustrates, you can see that there is not much weight at all required. --The vintage irons or a warmed pot/pan are usually the best alternative method, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Wear the clothes for about half a day at home.

The small irregular movements of wearing the clothing will render most wrinkles pretty invisible. After that, you can wear them to the occasion where they should be wrinkle-free.

This won't look good enough where there is a need / expectation to remove every last wrinkle. But it will look ok where the only expectation is to "look ok".

Answer (score -3):

Use a squirt bottle of water and slightly spray a mist onto the wrinkled area. Then throw the garment in the dryer until the dampness removed the wrinkles.

Comment: Although the OP accepted this answer, using a dryer won't work without electricity...

Comment: This answer completely ignores the conditions/limitations mentioned by the OP, and would not be helpful to anyone else who is looking for a similar solution.  If possible, please edit in and add a sufficient answer which meets the above limitations of no electricity (and therefore, no dryer).